# How to automatically create pictureboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I would like to automatically create a `PictureBox`. How to change this in the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox[] box = new PictureBox[textBox1.Text.Length];
    for(int j=0;j<textBox1.Text.Length;j++)
    box[0] = pictureBox1;
    box[1] = pictureBox2;
    box[2] = pictureBox3;
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; ++i) 
    box[i].Image = Image.FromFile(string.Format(@"c:\obrazki\{0}.jpg",textBox1.Text[i]));
}
```

Comment: what you want?? what is this with textBox1.Text.Length loop??

Comment: So, what isn't working? I can only guess that it's the created pictureboxes don't appear on your form, but without you saying anything it is just a guess.

Comment: to each character in the textbox is assigned one picturebox. I wish create automatically be entered in different length strings. I have string "abc" a=pictureBox1,b=pictrureBox2, c=pictureBox3. When i have 'ab" a=pictureBox1 b=pictureBox2. I would do it automatically. As I have 3 characters that Creates 3 ​​pictureboxy etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a FlowLayoutPanel control to hold your PictureBox controls.  Then the code would look something like this:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  while (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count > 0) {
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0].Dispose();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; ++i) {
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Image = Image.FromFile(string.Format(@"c:\obrazki\{0}.jpg",textBox1.Text[i]));
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the help. I lost a little bit of the pictureboxs